# Find closest datetime to specified datetime in mysql query

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I am trying to find a datetime value in a mysql database that is the closest match to a datetime that i specify, i am having some trouble.

The following pseudo code is what i want to achieve:

```
SELECT one FROM table WHERE datetimefield is closest to "2014-12-10 09:45:00" LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The key idea is to use `order by` and `limit`:

If you want the closest one before:

```
SELECT one
FROM table
WHERE datetimefield <= '2014-12-10 09:45:00'
ORDER BY datetimefield DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want the closest, in either direction, then use `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`:

```
ORDER BY abs(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, datetimefield, '2014-12-10 09:45:00'))
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i have updated the OP with an updated query that works but is very performance intensive if you would be so kind as to shed some light on it, cheers

Comment: @JackHayfield . . . That edited portion should be another question, not an addendum on this question.

Answer (score 6):

Using abs() prevents using a datetimefield index. I propose to have one select for the closest before and one select for the closest after, both using the index, and picking the closest of them afterwards:

```
create table `table` (datetimefield datetime key, one varchar(99));
insert into `table` values
  ('2014-06-01', 'a'), ('2014-12-01', 'b'),
  ('2015-01-01', 'c'), ('2015-02-01', 'd');

set @d = '2014-12-10 09:45:00';

select * from
(
  ( select *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @d, datetimefield) as diff
    from `table` where datetimefield >= @d
    order by datetimefield asc  limit 1
  )
  union
  ( select *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, datetimefield, @d) as diff
    from `table` where datetimefield < @d
    order by datetimefield desc limit 1
  )
) x
order by diff
limit 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bddb4/1

Comment: More complicated isn't necessarily a bad thing if it is better performance... which is the point of his post.

Answer (score 4):

Use [ABS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs)

```
SELECT one FROM table 
ORDER BY ABS(`datetimefield` - '2014-12-10 09:45:00') LIMIT 1
```

This will return the row with lowest difference, that is closest.